# excel: show cell address of todays date

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a row like this and want to know the cells address of todays date. This formula is returning an error as the col is not specified, cause I don't know which col it will be. Do you know how to solve this?

```
=cell("address";INDEX($2:$2;match(today();$2:$2;1);))
=CELL("address",INDEX(range,row,col))
```

[image]

Comment: are your "dates" actual dates or text?  If it is a date when you select the cell you should see something different in the formula bar than you see in the cell.  If they are the same then it is text and you will do something else.

Comment: Should it be `INDEX($2:$2; 1; match(today(); $2:$2; 1))`? You know the row is 1, and you want the match to give you the column.

Comment: @ScottCraner its a date. The 'match(today();$2:$2;1)' is returning the right value but now I need to know that adress not only the row to work with this in another formula

Comment: Then skip finding the address and just use Match in the formula you want.  there is no reason to use volatile formulas in a two step process.  Explain what you want in the end and we can help you skip this step.

Comment: @tehhowch yep, that it. I just had to remove the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Solutions go in the answers not in the question.  there is no reason that you cannot answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=ADDRESS(1,MATCH(TODAY(),1:1,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**
I had to remove the semicolon at the end. This is working now:

```
=cell("address";INDEX($2:$2;match(today();$2:$2;1)))
```